# saving my variables in a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a plot in which I had the "nuj" variable and an integration "Lnuj", now I want my values in a two column text file. the following is part of my code:

```
for j in range(N): 

    nuj = num*(nuM/num)**(j/N)
    Lnuj = integrate(nuj, Rin, Rout, N)
```

now I want nuj and Lnuj to be saved in a file. how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('{},{}'.format(nuj, Lnuj))
```

When you want to read these values you can use:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
    nuj, Lnuj = f.read().split(',')
```

Just take note that once you read them your values will be stored as strings and you'll need to convert them into desired format.

Comment: my file format is .py, does it still work like this?

Comment: Why would you save the values to the `.py`? You can save them to `.txt` and read them when you need them.